# Why is writing from R to Azure SQL Server is very slow

Tags: r, azure, odbc

I am trying to build out some data repositories in an Azure Managed Instance/Sql Server DB. I have been shocked by how slow the write process is, from R/RStudio. As an example, it took 65 minutes to write a table to Azure and less than one minute to write it to my local machine Sql Server.

It appears to write about 20 rows per second, regardless of the number of columns (if I refresh a query w/in SSMS, It's adding about 20 rows each time I run).

I have read in other threads that this could be due to the performance tier. I saw things about the B and A and P tiers. The only information I see on tiers in our account is "General Purpose" and "Business Critical". We have General Purpose (Gen5) with 8 cores and 512 GB of storage, of which we are utilizing less than 10%.  While performing one of these write operations from R the overall CPU Utilization is less than 1%.

I am able to read tables from Azure back to R/RStudio quickly. Only writing is significantly hampered.

All of this makes it feel like it's going much slower than it should, as if there was a throttling effect or something. It is so slow that I cannot effectively get historical data there-- I allowed several things to run last night and they all timed out.

Comment: Empircally and subjectively, I've found write-performance in R with most drivers to be much slower than expected, though for me it's not as low as 20/sec. As a workaround for larger inserts/queries I use the `sqlcmd` binary for bulk copies. The process of `data.table::fwrite` then `processx::run` is much much faster for me and worth the little overhead in code. (Side benefit, I can instead use processx::process$new` and allow it to run in the background allowing me to return to other R work.)

Comment: If for some reason R to Azure is just going to be slow (even the R to non-Azure SQL server is not), then I would consider doing something like this. I would probably not use `processx` to run from R but just schedule a batch file or something. I haven't used `sqlcmd` before. I figured out how to connect to the database but am not finding the syntax for how to create a table from a text file. Do you have a sample?

Comment: I don't use `sqlcmd` (or `bcp`) for creating tables. The way I work it, I have R wrapper code that "sets up" everything I need (including creating a table, if necessary), then use `sqlcmd` to upload the data. Over to you on `processx`, that's just (IMO) much better than `system` when initiating the process from R (not to mention I can background it and monitor/kill as necessary from R).

Comment: Can you share with me how you do the sqlcmd to upload the data then? I get what you're saying about using R to create the table etc. Granted that's not the focus of my original question but I'd like something else I can test to see if there is a significant performance improvement

Comment: `DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "sometable", mydata[1,])` to start the table (if new). Once the table exists, `write.csv(mydata[-1,], "temp.csv", row.names=FALSE)`, then `bcp` (mixup above), `bcp dbo.sometable in 'temp.csv' -F2 -f temp.fmt -D -S ipaddr,port -U user -d dbname -r '\r\n' -P pass`. The `fmt` file needs to be created and is based on the existing table, suggest you look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 or similar.

Comment: thank you. it's not working for me, but my issue is in getting authenticated. IT switched the db to multi-factor authentication and i've been struggling to get that to work across a variety of activities.